How to connect a 5-wire oven to a 3-wire electrical source?
I am in Dubai, I have an electric oven that came with a 5 wire connection I have to wire it into the oven and the wall. The wall has 3 wire connection
The oven is a Midea Vesta Electric Cooker VSVC96048
Can I bridge the 5 wire connection to the 3 terminals. How would I do it?
Wires for the oven:

Green Yellow - Ground
Blue - Neutral
Brown - power
Black - ?
Grey - ?

The owners manual only consults on the Ground, Neutral and Power
Having a diagram that indicates L1 L2 L3 etc



Some electrical devices like that might be set up for different phases.  Some might work on single phase(one live/power) like you have or might need all three phases(L2 and L3) or a mix of single, two phases, or three phases.  Without the oven make and model or the wiring diagram for that oven, we can only guess.

Midea Vesta Electric Cooker VSVC96048

I'd upload pics but I don't think I can on here

You can easily upload images to this site, use the edit function and the image button.

Thank you i was on my phone lol. So this is what im dealing with now that i have uploaded the pics. am i screwed and just have to get a different oven?

Please post a picture of the manual's page where the wiring instructions are given. I have tried to get a manual, but I cannot find one, and the manufacturer's website throws up an unremovable overlay that doesn't allow clicking on links on the web page.

@MarcusScott how many amps is the breaker for the oven circuit?

L3 is oven - heaters and electronics, L1 and L2 are for top plate heaters and electronics.
If schematics are right then do not connect this oven to one phase - need 3 phases to work.
Remember that You need certified electrician to install this oven or warranty will be void.
As manufacturer says it is 230V 15kW. If want even think about connecting it to 1 phase then need 45A breaker and at last 4.6mm wires...
